# Use html tags on the chartdata.labels using chart.js jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I am trying to show icomoon icons on chartjs labels but i am not able to do it. if i use html, it returns it as regular text.

https://jsfiddle.net/moviecrew/1sxhjzvo/6/ here is the fiddle i have been working on. i have tried doing something like this:

```
var socialMetLabel = ["<span class='icon-facebook'></span>", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
```

and chart option to like this:

```
data: {
        labels: socialMetLabel.slice(0, socialMetDisplayCount),
        // fontFamily: "'icomoon-font-tab', sans-serif",
        datasets: [{
            // label: false,
            data: socialMetData.slice(0, socialMetDisplayCount),
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(60, 143, 154, 0.16)',
            // backgroundColor: 'rgba(12, 125, 174, 0.2)',
            hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(60, 143, 154, 0.26)',
            borderWidth: 0,
            datalabels: {
                color: '#384354',
                font: {
                    family: '"Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji"',
                    size: 18,
                    weight: 'bold'
                },
                // clamp: true,
                anchor: 'end',
                align: 'end',
                // fontSize: '18px',
                // fontWeight: 'bold',
            }
        }]
    },

    // Configuration options go here
    options: {

        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,

        legend: {
          // display: chkLegend,
          display: false,
        },

        title: {
          display: false,
          text: 'Total leads vs Referred vs Direct leads',
        },

        tooltips: {
            enabled: false,
        },

        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            barPercentage: 0.8,
            categoryPercentage: 0.8,
            gridLines: {
                display: true,
                color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)',
                drawBorder: false,
                zeroLineColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)'
            },
            ticks: {
                min: 0,
                max: 200,
                stepSize: 25,
                fontFamily: '"Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji"',
                fontSize: 12,
                fontColor: '#AFB4BB',
                padding: 10
            },
            scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'Number of views',
                fontFamily: '"Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji"',
                fontSize: 12,
                // fontStyle: '300',
                fontColor: '#AFB4BB',
                padding: 10,
            }
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            categoryPercentage: 0.56,
            barPercentage: 1.0,
            gridLines: {
              display: false,
              color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)',
              drawBorder: false,
            },
            ticks: {
                fontFamily: 'icomoon',
                fontSize: 20,
                fontColor: '#384354',
                padding: 25,
                // callback: function(value, index, values) {
                //     return  + value + '</em>';
                // }
            }
          }],
        },
    }
```

it works fine if i use the character. It's coming from here https://tppr.me/3iyib but doing this, it's becomes difficult to make it dynamic and hard to recognize what icon is what later on.

so is there nay way we can make it work using either of these 3, `<span class="icon-facebook"></span>` or `&#xe95d;` or `"\e95d"` this. These are all that you can see in the screenshot i shared.